# Green flickering dots that move on my laptop screen

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have a Toshiba L50D-B83110 laptop (AMD A8 APU with AMD Radeon R5 M230 graphics) running Windows 8.1.

I have the same issue as the OP of this question: [Green flickering pixels that move with black images](https://superuser.com/questions/408279/green-flickering-pixels-that-move-with-black-images),
namely,

> Occasionally, on my LCD screen, pixels that should be black flicker rapidly and constantly between black and green, about 4 flickers a second.
>   The crazy part is, unlike dead/stuck pixels, they are relative to content on the screen and move with it. For example, when I'm watching movies or playing games, the green dots move along with the objects/characters in the game/movie.

To check whether the GPU's busted, I plugged in a monitor to discover that the monitor works fine. I hope this means there's probably nothing wrong with my GPU.
Now I'm wondering, Is it just a loose connection or a damaged LCD?

The drivers are up to date.

What could be causing this?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you suspect a loose connection or failing LCD (which could both cause it), then test those theories, as is, you're only asking us to guess if you're right..

Answer (score 1):

If you're question has been posted elsewhere with similar symptoms but different setup/diagnostics... I recommend providing a little more manual description and detail than just a link.

In any case, I personally would rule out a bad GPU if it works fine on an external monitor. That would leave only two potential culprits.

~ Bad LCD: Usually this means consistent white lines, dead pixels, etc... as mentioned in the link it's still within the realm of possibility.

~ Bad Ribbon cable: Obviously this is mostly exhibited through screen flickering, not changing artifacts, but again, still possible.

These are a little harder to firmly diagnose without a spare cable/screen but tinkering with the connection and disassembly has worked for me in the past. Besides, what have you got to loose? I agree with Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, you should test the theories you've heard of or are considering rather than asking us to guess on your behalf.

Comment: RAM would affect both an external monitor and the built-in LCD. I would guess bad cable or bad LCD panel.

Comment: oh, psh. Duh... edited that one out.