# Is this a faulty video card?

Tags: video, graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I've recently bought a Thinkpad P1 with Xeon processor with an nVidia Quadro P2000 (with Max-Q Design, whatever that is) and I've been noticing some video artifacts. Recently, when a particular website grayed out most of the page due to a pop in, I could see it plainly and I recorded a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOQ9vWYNKdQ

If you wait till the end of the video, you can see it is only happening in the grayed out area of the website. As soon as the grayed out effect goes, so does the problem. These monitors are connected to two computers and I've never seen anything like that when on the other computer.

Is this the sign of a faulty video card?

Comment: With a faulty video card, the artifacts such as the dots over the image, wouldn't be limited to one image.

Comment: I had similar, but green. Replace the cable between the monitor and computer, or make sure it is fitted securely into both sides.

Comment: Can you hook up an external monitor to see if it exhibits the same problem?  To me it looks like partially defective pixels in the screen.  Like R in RGB is sometimes being defective.  I have a couple on my monitor, but the colors on my screen usually mask the problem.

Comment: @Mokubai: it only appeared when the web site was grayed out, you can see towards the end, when I dismiss the pop-in and the website goes back to normal, the problem disappears. Do you think it can still be the cable?

Comment: @cybernard: that was an external monitor. The red pixels and horizontal lines only appeared when the website was grayed out. Otherwise, the monitor is just fine.

Comment: @pupeno frankly, yes. https://superuser.com/questions/408279/green-flickering-pixels-that-move-with-black-images/441218#441218