# DVI vs. HDMI Picture Quality - is there a difference?

Tags: hdmi, dvi

DVI vs. HDMI Picture Quality - is there a difference  between the two of them for a computer monitor - does this depend on the cable used and the cable quality ?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a difference in color range as HDMI is typically used for TV, but you can change that in your graphic card settings.

Newer HDMI versions support higher bitrates which in turn allow higher colour depths (10 bit per colour) and HDR, so again can look better.

But for the same resolution, bit depth and so on, they will be identical. They are both digital signalling methods so the cable should not matter, but lower quality cables can cause noise and interference.

Comment: I think DVI is electrically identical to older HDMI versions, so passive adapters are possible. Newer features you mention are not available with these adapters though.

Comment: They are identical and their cables can be switched. The difference is only that audio is only supported by HDMI.

Comment: "noise and interference" in digital terms is not picture quality per se, but rather glitches, incomplete frames and other types of problems that make video unwatchable as opposed to fuzzy, banded gradients, oversharp etc.

Comment: @Yorik indeed, it is not "fuzziness" or general blurring of colours, but apparently [flickering Green pixels](https://superuser.com/questions/408279/green-flickering-pixels-that-move-with-black-images/441218#441218) is not uncommon and is something I have experienced.

Answer (score 2):

The cable has nothing to do with the picture quality, it's the interface and protocol over it.

DVI only supports 8-bit RGB colors, but it comes with single and dual link varieties.

HDMI supports faster speeds larger resolutions, up to 12-bit colors, and other colorspaces than RGB, but if your monitor or video card only supports say 1920x1200 at 60 Hz and 8-bit over HDMI, then that is the best you can get anyway and it does not matter if you use DVI or HDMI interface.

And, it depends on your monitor, if it allows for same resolutions to be used over HDMI and DVI. Some will, some won't, as DVI is primarily meant for computer monitor connection, and HDMI is primarily meant as a television connection.

Comment: That explains it.  I ended up getting a DVI to USB adapter and even though the monitor can accept HDMI connections I am using DVI and the resolution color wise on the DVI monitor is not as good as the HDMI connected monitor.  Didnt know the color 8 disparity difference between DVI and HDMI

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Absolutely 100% yes. Powerpoint is a huge offender offering use of the full color palette range so when you toss two monitors viewing the same thing, one HDMI, one DVI, the DVI will loose color info sometimes if the source is not in the RGB range.

Seen it happen, big time.