# What could cause shimmering dots in an HDMI-connected monitor?

Tags: hdmi

I saw this screen at a local clinic. It's connected with HDMI to the source, presumably a PC.

What could cause the shimmering dots all over the image? For example, on the guy's sleeve.

*[Edit]* I'm not referring to the moiré pattern - that's clearly a photography artifact.
[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/408279/green-flickering-pixels-that-move-with-black-images/441218#441218 poor quality cables is my experience with this.

Comment: Is it positioned next to any other equipment?

Comment: @stark: Not that I can see. But the HDMI cable disappears behind the drywall, and there could be all sorts of stuff in there